# Shuffle list of products while querying

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Products and Category table in a database:

Products has the following columns:
ProductId, ProductName, Description, Path, Name, URL, CategoryId, Active

Category has the following columns:
CategoryId, CategoryName

I have written a LINQ statement to query the database and fetch the products for the relevant category. The query works fine.

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts(
                     [QueryString("id")] int? categoryId,
                     [RouteData] string categoryName)
{
    var _db = new products.Models.ProductContext();
    IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;

    if (categoryId.HasValue && categoryId > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.CategoryID == categoryId);
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName))
    {
        query = query.Where(p =>
                            String.Compare(p.Category.CategoryName,
                            categoryName) == 0);
    }
    return query;
}
```

I have two doubts:

1. How can I modify this query to select only those products that have Active = 1.
2. Currently the query returns the row in a particular order I think based on productId - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. How can I shuffle the results so that the results are not returned in a particular order. It could be 5, 2, 4, 1, 3 or for the next run 3, 5, 1, 4, 2 and so on.

Comment: Is returning `IQueryable<Product>` a requirement, i.e. is it allowed to change the signature of the method to return `IEnumerable<Product>` for instance? If not, is it allowed to materialize the query inside the method?

Comment: If I change it to IEnumerable, how will it benefit/solve my requirement?

Comment: Benefit - no, solve - yes (the second part - randomization). Look at the current answer. I don't think there is a way to do randomization using `IQueryable`. That's why we need to materialize (i.e. execute) the query and then randomize. Of course we can always turn enumerable to queryable, but that kills the whole idea of queryable against db.

Comment: It might be better to keep the signature and just add the `p.Active == 1` criteria. This way you could use the function and apply `'Count()', or addition criteria, or select etc. And create another generic method that does randomization. Sounds good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the shuffle part. It can't be done with `IQueryable`, so better introduce a generic extension method is some common place:

```
public static void Swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)
{
    var temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
public static T[] RandomShuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var result = source.ToArray();
    if (result.Length < 2) return result;
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = result.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int pos = random.Next(i + 1);
        if (pos != i) Swap(ref result[pos], ref result[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now your function:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts(
                     [QueryString("id")] int? categoryId,
                     [RouteData] string categoryName)
{
    var _db = new products.Models.ProductContext();
    IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
    query = query.Where(p => p.Active == 1); // the first question
    if (categoryId.HasValue && categoryId > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.CategoryID == categoryId);
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName))
    {
        query = query.Where(p =>
                            String.Compare(p.Category.CategoryName,
                            categoryName) == 0);
    }
    return query;
}
```

You can keep it this way (which IMO is better) and apply shuffle at the call side when you need that behavior, like  `GetProducts(....).RandomShuffle()`. Or, if you insist doing it inside, just change the last line to `return query.RandomShuffle().AsQueryable();`

Comment: I am not sure what is happening. I am using GetProducts like this <asp:ListView ID="productList" runat="server" 
                DataKeyNames="ProductID" GroupItemCount="6"
                ItemType="products.Models.Product" SelectMethod="GetProducts">. I can debug and see that the rows are getting shuffled but when it appears on the ListView, they appear ordered.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that control, I guess it could be applying some sorting internally.

Answer (score 0):

To filter for the Active products, just extend the query by the following:

```
query = query.Where(p => p.CategoryID == categoryId && p.Active == 1);
```

To shuffle the result, you'll have to code something yourself. It will probably be something like this:

```
var shuffledList = new List<Product>();
var originalList = query.ToList();
var random = new Random();

while (originalList.Count() > 0) {
    var pick = random.Next(0, originalList.Count());
    var product = originalList[pick];
    shuffledList.Add(product);
    originalList.Remove(product);
}
```

The `shuffledList` will then contain your products in a randomized order. You'll have some loard on memory though, as you have twice the amount of products in your memory.

Another possibility I just came across would be:

```
var random = new Random();    
query = query.OrderBy(product => random.Next());
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it out. In each Category, I have about 30 products. How to I find out how many products are being returned?

Comment: Just use `query.Count()`. This will materialize the results though, so it will execute the query.

Comment: That extension for Active products will only work if a `categoryId` is submitted. Why not make it a separate `Where`?

Comment: @Rawling Can you explain how to make it a separate Where?

Comment: @IWantToLearn Ivan's answer has it on the line commented `// the first question`.